Unreasonable rebooking of cancelled flight
Flying from Dallas via Chicago the connecting flight to Reykjavik was cancelled after a 3-hour delay. It was rebooked at 1 am with an error on the ticket showing 2 flights the next day. The actual flights were day one overnight flight at 10:30 pm to Frankfurt and day two at 9:40 pm arriving in Reykjavik at 11:30 pm with customs to be cleared and transport to hotel to be on a tour bus by 8 am.
I am 74 traveling alone, joining a tour group, and found this to be ill-advised to undertake this itinerary. Insurance has classified this as a missed connection rather than a trip interruption. I feel age discrimination and complete disregard of circumstances.
I would have only had maybe 5 hours of sleep in 72 hours time, after only 4 hours of sleep the night of the cancellation. Plus the stress of maneuvering through customs in a country not on my original itinerary. How can I obtain compensation?

Which airline? What did they say when you told them the re-booking was not acceptable?

A US airline re-booked with foreign airline. They said no other flights available. Foreign carrier said US Cartier had to make any changes.
